# Changing style of Kendo CheckBox in a Grid

Tags: angular, user-interface, checkbox, kendo-ui, grid

How can I change the style of all the checkboxes?

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-g3iqix

When I try to apply any classes its just applied to Select All Checkbox not all of them?
Lets say I want to add a different border to all the checkbox how can that be implemented? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can target this:

```
.k-checkbox-label::before {

    background-color: #222232;
}
```